# How to get Jackson mixin to handle an included type?

Tags: java, jackson

I'm using Jackson mixins to only serialize out specific fields.

My ObjectMapper is configured like so:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL, Visibility.NONE);
mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
mapper.addMixIn(Person.class, SyncPerson.class);
mapper.addMixIn(TransactionLog.class, TransactionLogExport.class);
```

Here are the model classes paired with the JSON mixin objects that I'd like to export:

```
// Model class
public class Person {
    private Long id;
    private String email;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
}

// Desired JSON format.  Excludes 'id' field
public interface SyncPerson {

    @JsonProperty("firstName")
    String getFirstName();

    @JsonProperty("lastName")
    String getLastName();

    @JsonProperty("email")
    String getEmail();
}


// Model class
public class TransactionLog {
    private long id;
    private Integer version;
    private Person person;
    private Date date;
    private EntityAction action;
}

// Desired JSON format.  Excludes 'id' field, 'version', 'date'
public interface TransactionLogExport {

    @JsonProperty("id")
    String getId();

    @JsonProperty("person")
    Person person();

    @JsonProperty("action")
    EntityAction getAction();
}
```

Yet, my tests are showing that the `person` attribute of the TransactionLog isn't coming through.

```
@Test
public void testWriteValue() throws Exception {
    Person person = new Person();
    person.setEmail("a@c.com");
    person.setFirstName("A");
    person.setLastName("C");

    TransactionLog log = new TransactionLog();
    log.setId(0L);
    log.setAction(EntityAction.CREATE);
    log.setPerson(person);
    log.setStartValue("start");
    log.setEndValue("end");
    log.setChanges("change");

    String prettyJson = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(log); 
    System.out.println(prettyJson);
    // Prints:
    // {
    //   "id" : 0,
    //   "action" : "CREATE",
    }
}
```

If I try the same test with a regular `ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();` instead of the mixin, then I see the full object exported, including the `Person` with email, names, etc.  So something must be wrong with how I've configured the mixin... or else I'm misunderstanding something.

So can anyone help indicate what I could do to export out the subtype 'person' in my mixin?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured out the issue.  The test now prints what we want:

```
{
  “id” : 0,
  “person” : {
    “email” : “a@c.com”,
    “firstName” : “A”,
    “lastName” : “C”
  },
  “action” : “CREATE”
}
```

The mistake was in `TransactionLogExport`.  It needs to say:

```
@JsonProperty("person")
Person getPerson();
```

Instead of:

```
@JsonProperty("person")
Person person();
```

I.e. the method needs to start with 'get'.